# File Count program is shell not quite working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
# File Count


if (( $# < 2 )) 
then
echo "${0}: ERROR: Incorrect number of arguments entered." 1>&2 
echo "${0}: USAGE: ${0} <directory> <filename>" 1>&2 
exit 1 
fi 

#checks for a valid number of arguments then exits if the user doesn't provide them and       shows an error message.

if [[ ! -d "${1}" ]] 
then 
echo "${0}: ERROR: directory ${1} does not exist." 1>&2 
echo "${0}: USAGE: ${0} <directory> <filename>" 1>&2 
exit 2 
fi
#checks for a the directory the user specified then exits if the user doesn't provide a valid directory and shows an error message.


if [[ -d "${1}" ]]
then
typeset -i directoryCount=0 
for files in $(ls) 
do 
((directoryCount++)) 
done

# if it's a directory file add 1 to the directory count


if [[ -x "${1}" ]]
then
typeset -i executableCount=0 
for files in $(ls) 
do 
((executableCount++)) 
done
# if it's a executable file add 1 to the executable count

if [[ -f "${1}" ]]
then
typeset -i ordinaryCount=0 
for files in $(ls) 
do 
((ordinaryCount++)) 
done
 # if it's a ordinary file add 1 to the ordinary count

echo The number of directory files is "${directoryCount}" 
echo The number of executable files is "${executableCount}"
echo The number of ordinary files is "${ordinaryCount}" 

#display file counts
```

Having trouble with this program although I think I'm along the right lines.Can anyone offer insight? Below is what what it needs to do.Thanks.

1. If pathname of directory is blank then exit with error message.
2. If pathname of directory given does not name an existing directory then exit with 
   error message.
3. If directory content cannot be read then exit with error message.
4. Initialise variables to hold the three counts
5. Loop through each file in the directory named:
6. if it is a directory count it as such;
7. if it is executable count it as such
8. if it is an ordinary file count it as such
9. output the results.

Comment: `if [[ -d "${1}" ]]` is always going to be true since you've already checked that the opposite is not true. Don't [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) just use `for file in *`. Is the question here about how to add the `is executable` logic?

Comment: Why require a second argument that is never used?  Why not just use `find` and pipe the output to `wc`?

Comment: It's always the logic I struggle with during these things quite new to this type of programming aswell

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to give you a head start with something I cooked up after reading your script and description. I think it's pretty self-explanatory. Your requirements 1 and 3 are not implemented, as for 1 I believe that a fall-back to the current working directory is more useful.

This is the very basic script, which should give you plenty of space for enhancements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Either set DIR upon calling or submit a parameter or fall back to the CWD
: ${DIR:="${1:-.}"}

if [ ! -d "${DIR}" ]; then
    echo "${0##*/}: ERROR: Directory '${DIR}' does not exist." 
    echo "${0##*/}: USAGE: ${0##*/} <directory>" 
    exit 1
else
    echo "Investigating directory: ${DIR}"
fi

function initVars() {
    directoryCount=0
    executableCount=0
    ordinaryCount=0
    unknownTypeCount=0
}

function checkOwnerExecutable() {
    local permStr=$1
    # return 0 if executable bit is set, otherwise 1
    [ "x${owner//x/}" != "x${owner}" ] && return 0 || return 1
}

initVars
while read entry; do
    #echo "entry: ${entry}"
    eval ${entry}
    case "$type" in
        "Directory")
            let directoryCount+=1
            ;;
        "Regular File")
            let ordinaryCount+=1
            checkOwnerExecutable $owner && let executableCount+=1
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown type=$type with name=$name"
            let unknownTypeCount+=1
            ;;
    esac
done < <(stat -f 'name="%N" type="%HT" owner="%SHp" group="%SMp" other="%SLp"' ${DIR}/* ${DIR}/.*)

echo "The number of directory files is ${directoryCount}" 
echo "The number of executable files is ${executableCount}"
echo "The number of ordinary files is ${ordinaryCount}"
echo "The number of unknown type files is ${unknownTypeCount}"
```

And here is the output for /tmp:

```
$ ./fileCount.sh /tmp
Investigating directory: /tmp
Unknown type=Socket with name=/tmp/textmate-501.sock
Unknown type=Socket with name=/tmp/.prl_pcsc_gate
The number of directory files is 11
The number of executable files is 1
The number of ordinary files is 4
The number of unknown type files is 2
```

It includes/counts the "." and ".." files as directories too. If you don't want that, adjust the stat command at the end of the while loop.